# Stylesheets and javascript not read in Spring application

Tags: javascript, css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

If I open the html file without Spring, the css and js files loads correctly. But when I run it as a Spring application, css and js files has no effect and the output is just a bare html page.

I have tried adding the path both using thymeleaf and normal links as follows. No difference in both attempts and no error messages either.

Looked around and been advised to move the files to a static folder. That doesn't help either. Please advice. Thank you.

**Project Structure**

[image]

Adding links to js and css files. Autocomplete suggests the correct files which I believe indicates files in correct location.

```
<!--<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"/>-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css"/>-->

<link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link th:href="@{https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link th:href="@{../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
<link th:href="@{../static/css/style.css}"/>

<script th:src="@{../static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}" type="javascript"></script>
<script th:src="@{../static/js/jquery.min.js}" type="javascript"></script>
<script th:src="@{../static/js/index.js}" type="javascript"></script>
<!--<script src='../static/js/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
<!--<script src="../static/js/index.js"></script>-->
```

gradle file

```
group 'com.fantasy'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-securing-web'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
}
```

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "../static" in the links and it will work. Your files are mapped to URLs. So when you access your server, you don't access to it like to you filesystem-structure. Spring-Boot default defines the needed ResourceMapping.

Comment: Tried <link th:href="@{css/style.css}"/> Sane results.

Comment: did you customized the default config of Spring Boot?

Comment: No, I've left them as defaults.

Comment: Hm. Did you customized Spring Security? At default Spring maps all files in "static" folder to URL-Root...

Comment: Didn't make any changes to Spring Security either. Added gradle file and java files in case they might help identify issue.

Comment: I think the problem is @EnableWebSecurity. It overrides Spring Boots default Security, so you don't have access to any files without login. So remove it...

Comment: Same results. Not sure if security would be causing issues with accessing static files like css and js.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot very long and im sure, that /css/style.css is right. The problem seems to be elsewere. What messege do you get when you try to access it with your browser (e.g. https://localhost:8080/css/style.css)?

Comment: Resolved by adding rel="stylesheet" to css link and text/javascript instead of javascript to js file link. Thank you.